# cannot call api on android app but its working on browser

Tags: ionic3

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.6.0 
   native-run  : 0.2.7

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

It should be called with Ip address, you can't use localhost into your ionic project 
  if they are running in the same network, or you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that will generate an https-URL for your API